# ObservableCollection does not update UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

On startup i bind an ObservableCollection to a menu:

```
Menu.ItemsSource = _manager.Selection;
```

This menu correctly displays all objects from the collection.

Now i want to update the collection and add/remove some of the items in it:

```
private void OnBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _manager.Selection = _manager.GetNewSelection();
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new CollectionChangeEventArgs(CollectionChangeAction.Refresh, _manager.Selection));
    }

    public event CollectionChangeEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

But the ui is still displaying how it was before..

What is missing?

Comment: Why is it an ObservableCollection at all, when you seemingly never add or remove elements? Use an ordinary `public List<Selection> Selections` property that fires the PropertyChanged event of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface when it is set.

Answer (score 1):

You should either re-set the `Menu.ItemsSource` property (to `_manager.GetNewSelection()`) or add or remove items from `_manager.Selection`. Setting the `_manager.Selection` field to another instance of an `ObservableCollection<T>` won't affect the menu's `ItemsSource` property.

If you get a completely new collection from the `_manager.GetNewSelection()`, you might as well just do this:

```
private void OnBoxClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Menu.ItemsSource = _manager.GetNewSelection();
}
```

And then it doesn't matter whether `_manager.GetNewSelection` returns an `ObservableCollection` or any other kind of `IEnumerable` that doesn't provide notifications when items are added or removed.

Comment: or use `Binding` to ding menu's `itemsSource` to manager's `Selection` property

Comment: Yes, but since OnBoxClick apparently is an event handler in the view, there is no real point of binding here.

Comment: so right now i cleared the selection, and then added the "new" objects. After that i fired the propertychanged event but it still doesnt refresh the menu. I also tried to set itemssource = _manager.GetNetSelection() but it still doesnt refresh the ui

Comment: @Loading: Then you are touching the wrong instance or the collection hasn't changed.

Comment: the problem was that i cant use this code in a menu "onclick" function. I had to use mouseenter to trigger the "update"

Comment: @Loading: This has nothing to do with your original question. If your issue has been solved, please remember to accept the answer to close it.